# ggplot theme text sizes not working in RShiny - works on first deploy then goes small

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm having a weird bug with some RShiny work I'm doing. I have set ggplot themes that should apply each time a ggplot is rendered. When I first deploy the app to the internet, the sizes come out correctly. However, as soon as you interact with the plot, the sizes become unworkably small and do not return to their intended sizes.

Initial deployment:
[image]

After interacting:
[image]

I am using showtext with showtext_auto() just before rendering the plot, and a google font "Jost", but this also seems to happen with default fonts and not using showtext. It's rather frustrating and would be great if anyone has encountered this before and know why it might be happening!

The ggplot code is inside of a renderPlot section, which has quite a bit of other code in it to determine which of the plot options to plot and too much too share the whole thing:

```
        ggplot(plot_data) +
      coord_flip() +
      scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .05))) +
      geom_col(aes(y = pct, x = !!sym(variable_selection)), fill = blue, alpha = .8) +
      labs(y = "Percent",
           title = glue::glue("Location: {input$specific_geo}"),
           subtitle = glue::glue("Variable: {input$main_variable}")) +
      theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            plot.title.position = "plot",
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
            panel.grid = element_line(color = "grey91"),
            panel.border = element_rect(color = "grey85", fill = NA),
            text = element_text(color = "black", size = 14, family = "Jost"),
            axis.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 14),
            axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 14, family = "Jost"),
            panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

Comment: Could you share the code at least for how you set the theme and make the plot?

Comment: I'm adding the specific ggplot and theme code to the main question

Comment: And when there are plot interactions, is that calling this same code or do you have code to modify the plot object?

Comment: There are a few different ggplot calls within the same render plot and so depending on whether certain different if statements are met, it ends up calling another ggplot() that has different (but with the same theme etc.) code to this. I think it may be to do with the use of showtext because in fact trying it again but cutting out anything to do with showtext the sizes come out reasonable again - but I really don't like the ggplot/shiny default font family!

Comment: I think it is probably something to do with showtext using a different auto font size that is related to the dpi of the graphics device (https://github.com/yixuan/showtext/issues/51) but I'm not sure how to incorporate this info to get a good and consistent size

Comment: You may want to consider defining your theme once and using `theme_set()` to update the default theme. It would make your code cleaner to use DRY that way, and might end up making it easier to find the problem.